# Where is gsl installed - fedora 24

Tags: linux, fedora

I am trying to build a plotting software called `qtiplot`. I find it extremely difficult to do it. The thing is that when I run `qmake && make` I get the following error

> ```
> In file included from src/analysis/Fit.cpp:29:0:
>   src/analysis/Fit.h:37:35: fatal error: gsl/gsl_multifit_nlin.h: No such file    or directory
>    #include <gsl/gsl_multifit_nlin.h
> ```

I think that this has to do with the fact, that it cannot find the headers files provided by `gsl`.

I tried to search for these header files by using

```
locate gsl_multifit_nlin.h
```

or

```
find -name "gsl_multifit_nlin.h"
```

but I couldn't find anything.

So my question is where can I find "where" gsl is installed in order to see where the header files are, to modify accordingly `qtiplot`'s header files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked which package you need to have installed in order to have the `gsl_multifit_nlin.h` header file, and it's the `gsl-devel` one. If the package is successfully installed on the system (check with the `dnf list installed | grep gsl-devel` command), the file should be located in the `/usr/include/gsl/` directory (at least on my F24). If the check for installed package fails, you need to install it.

However, there are possible issues with your searches in case the package is indeed installed:

The `locate` command you show in the question successfully finds this file. You may have forgot to run `sudo updatedb` after the installation. This command updates the database used by `locate` command, and if it wasn't run after package installation, the `locate` command has no idea new files are present.

Also, which directory are you running the `find` command from? In the form you present it, you need to run it from root directory since it doesn't automatically search the whole system, only recursively from the directory it was called (for example, if run in the home directory, it searches only the home directory and not the `/etc/` one).